# python subprocess - google-chrome headless - self-signed certificate - screenshot

Tags: django, subprocess, ssl-certificate, headless, python-3.11

When opening a django shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

and typing in:

```
import subprocess
command = [
  f'google-chrome',
  '--headless=new',
  f'--screenshot=/home/user/tmp/screen.png',
  f'--window-size=800,1700',
  '--no-first-run',
  '--allow-http-screen-capture',
  '--force-device-scale-factor=1',
  '--ignore-certificate-errors',
  '--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests',
  '--disable-test-root-certs',
  '--allow-running-insecure-content',
  '--hide-scrollbars',
  '--allow-insecure-localhost',
  '--disable-system-font-check',
  '--disable-gpu',
  '--disable-extensions',
  '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
  '--disable-software-rasterizer',
  '--disable-notifications',
  '--user-data-dir=/tmp/chromium-home',
  '/home/user/tmp/screen.html',
]
subprocess.run(command, **{})
```

The console output is the following:

```
[32873:32901:0419/083534.872076:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/0/bus: Permission denied
[32873:32901:0419/083534.884135:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/0/bus: Permission denied
[32873:32901:0419/083534.970536:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/0/bus: Permission denied
[32873:32901:0419/083534.970630:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/0/bus: Permission denied

(process:32873): dconf-CRITICAL **: 08:35:35.289: unable to create directory '/run/user/0/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(process:32873): dconf-CRITICAL **: 08:35:35.314: unable to create directory '/run/user/0/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(process:32873): dconf-CRITICAL **: 08:35:35.350: unable to create directory '/run/user/0/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
[32873:32899:0419/083537.631303:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(679)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for 127.0.0.1 failed:
----- Certificate i=0 (<snip>) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found


[32873:32897:0419/083537.639022:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(679)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for 127.0.0.1 failed:
----- Certificate i=0 (<snip>) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found


572051 bytes written to file /home/user/tmp/screen.png
CompletedProcess(args=['google-chrome', '--headless=new', '--screenshot=/home/user/tmp/screen.png', '--window-size=800, 1700', '--no-first-run', '--allow-http-screen-capture', '--force-device-scale-factor=1', '--ignore-certificate-errors', '--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests', '--disable-test-root-certs', '--allow-running-insecure-content', '--hide-scrollbars', '--allow-insecure-localhost', '--disable-system-font-check', '--disable-gpu', '--disable-extensions', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-software-rasterizer', '--disable-notifications', '--user-data-dir=/tmp/chromium-home', '/home/user/tmp/screen.html'], returncode=0)
```

Looks worrying, but the `screen.png` file is properly "screenshotted".
We can even see the certificate errors, which are mentioned but apparently ignored as requested in the subprocess call.

By the way, the bash calling works too, i.e., :

```
$ google-chrome --headless=new --screenshot=/home/user/tmp/screen.png --window-size=800,1700 --no-first-run --allow-http-screen-capture --force-device-scale-factor=1 --ignore-certificate-errors --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests --disable-test-root-certs --allow-running-insecure-content --hide-scrollbars --allow-insecure-localhost --disable-system-font-check --disable-gpu --disable-extensions --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-software-rasterizer --disable-notifications --user-data-dir=/tmp/chromium-home /home/user/tmp/screen.html
```

works too.

Google chrome version is `google-chrome-unstable.x86_64 114.0.5696.0-1` on Rocky Linux 9. The problem described below is the same with the stable version.

Now I would like to ru the above subprocess call from within a model function, like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    <snip>

    def render(self):
        import subprocess
        commands = [
            f'google-chrome',
            '--headless=new',
            f'--screenshot=/home/user/tmp/screen.png',
            f'--window-size=800,1700',
            '--no-first-run',
            '--allow-http-screen-capture',
            '--force-device-scale-factor=1',
            '--ignore-certificate-errors',
            '--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests',
            '--disable-test-root-certs',
            '--allow-running-insecure-content',
            '--hide-scrollbars',
            '--allow-insecure-localhost',
            '--disable-system-font-check',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--disable-extensions',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--disable-software-rasterizer',
            '--disable-notifications',
            '--user-data-dir=/tmp/chromium-home',
            '/home/user/tmp/screen.html',
        ]
        subprocess.run()
```

The command line output is:

```
[33681:33708:0419/085053.463656:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/0/bus: Permission denied
[33681:33708:0419/085053.464599:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/0/bus: Permission denied
[33681:33708:0419/085053.589267:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/0/bus: Permission denied
[33681:33708:0419/085053.589373:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/0/bus: Permission denied

(process:33681): dconf-CRITICAL **: 08:50:53.761: unable to create directory '/run/user/0/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(process:33681): dconf-CRITICAL **: 08:50:53.768: unable to create directory '/run/user/0/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(process:33681): dconf-CRITICAL **: 08:50:53.821: unable to create directory '/run/user/0/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
8899 bytes written to file /home/user/tmp/screen.png
```

Errors are similar, but the SSL certificate errors are not there.

Given that the contents of the HTML file are (or very similar, the file is dynamically generated):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">
<style>
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html{
    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
}
.upload{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1600px;
    width:800px;
    display:block;
}
.upload > img{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="upload">
<img src="https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/_static/celery_512.png"><br>
<img src="https://127.0.0.1:1310/m/u/befe5aa9-690b-410d-a3bc-7ba9a75c382a.webp" alt="This is a test">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am guessing `subnprocess` is somehow skipping? ignoring? discarding? the image calls made by the headless browser?

In a word:

- works from bash command line
- works from "normal" python shell
- does not work from an object method

I am at a loss -- any clues?

Answer (score 1):

If you'll excuse my French, I am an idiot :)
Will post the answer for posterity and since the internet is forever, as a reminder for myself. :-|

the answer was in the dynamic generation of the HTML file:

Broken version:

```
def render(self):
     html_render = '<some /><markup />'
     with open(temp_html_full_path, 'w') as f:
         f.write(html_render)
         command = []
         subprocess.run(command, **{})
```

Working version:

```
def render(self):
     html_render = '<some /><markup />'
     with open(temp_html_full_path, 'w') as f:
         f.write(html_render)
     command = []
     subprocess.run(command, **{})
```

Notice how the `subprocess` call is made inside/outside the `with` file writing block.